# @azure/msal-browser TypeError: this.startPerformanceMeasurement is not a function

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

## Introduction

Because there is no build in Auth library for nuxt 3 yet, I am trying to create my own composable called useAuth.

## The Problem

I am getting a startPerformanceMeasurement error when i try to call the loginRedirect or loginPopup method.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.startPerformanceMeasurement is not a function
    at PerformanceClient2.startMeasurement (PerformanceClient.ts:100:45)
    at BrowserPerformanceClient2.startMeasurement (BrowserPerformanceClient.ts:46:55)
    at RedirectClient2.<anonymous> (StandardInteractionClient.ts:204:64)
    at step (_tslib.js:87:23)
    at Object.next (_tslib.js:68:53)
    at _tslib.js:61:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (_tslib.js:57:12)
    at StandardInteractionClient2.getDiscoveredAuthority (StandardInteractionClient.ts:202:115)
    at RedirectClient2.<anonymous> (StandardInteractionClient.ts:142:48)
```

## Code

**composables/useAuth.js**

```js
import * as msal from '@azure/msal-browser'

let state = {
    authService: null,  
}

export const useAuth = () => {
    // use public configuration from nuxt 
    var config = useAppConfig();
    //create authentication instance
    state.authService = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config.msalConfig);

    //return signIn method
    return {
        signIn
    }
}

const signIn = async () => {
    const tokenRequest = {
        scopes: [
            'openid', 
            'offline_access', 
            'Users.Read'
        ],
    }
    const response = await state.authService
        .loginRedirect(tokenRequest)
        .then(() => {

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err) //TypeError: this.startPerformanceMeasurement is not a function
        });
}
```

**Index.vue**

```js
<script setup>
if(process.client) {
    const auth = useAuth()
    auth.signIn()   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Same here, my version works in javascript, but does not in typescript

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. The strange thing is that this is working on my local but when deployed on our dev env it is throwing error. On local I tried to run this by making a build on local as well.

Comment: deleted the npm module and lock file. now i am able to reproduce it on my local.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in the MSAL library.

As mentioned in [this issue on Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5569#issuecomment-1386190629), they're currently working on a fix.

As a temporary solution, you could downgrade to a previous version. Downgrading might be as simple as just removing the caret character (^) when referring to the version in your package.json.

Edit: They've released a fix as part of msal-common v9.1.1.

Comment: Form the comments in that same thread, change your **package.json** dependencies to:  
`"@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.0",  
"@azure/msal-common": "9.0.1",  
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.0",`
(important, remove the `^` if present)

Answer (score 3):

I tested by downgrading multiple releases and the first one working was @azure/msal-browser@2.31.0

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue too. It is caused due to a bug from Microsoft. The versions that work fine are:

"@azure/msal-browser": "2.32.0",
"@azure/msal-common": "9.0.1",
"@azure/msal-react": "1.5.0",

Please ensure to remove the ^ in the number to keep it pinned.
Watch https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5569 for updates from MS.

Comment: Yes, we removed the ^ and it works too.